# Anchor offset isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, offset

I made a page with a fixed header, where I want to use smooth scrolling (jQuery).
Because of the fixed header I need to add an offset to my anchor links.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4s390e/

I tried setting the anchors like this

```
<a id="top" class="anchor"></a>
```

and then adding a CSS class

```
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    top: -110px;
    height: 110px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work for me and I have no idea why.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very good description of a problem ?

Comment: In my eyes - together with the jsfiddle - it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using CSS. I had to set my anchors like this

```
<div class="anchor"><span id="section1"></span></div>
```

and define them in my CSS like this

```
.anchor{            position: relative;}

.anchor span{       margin-top: -110px;
                    padding-bottom: 110px;
                    display: block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
```

That seems to get the desird result.